# X-Accel-Mapping header missing in Puma error log

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, puma

I just move from unicorn to puma and I saw `X-Accel-Mapping header missing` this message in Puma error log.

What does that mean? Where should I look into for this problem?

Thanks a lot.

I am running the latest Puma with Rails 4.2.1 behind Nginx.

Comment: Just as lost as you @Larry but I think this has to do with serving large files from your application.  If you don't need to do this, you may be able to remove related lines from your NGINX configuration and Puma will stop complaining.